# Get DDMMYYYY format in SQL Server without periods or hyphens

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little task to do and I need to get **ddmmyyyy** format for my `DateTime` values in SQL Server.

I tried to do it with this code

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)
```

and it works fine, but it returns `dd.mm.yyyy` or `01.11.2021`. I need it to be `01112021` but I can't achieve this yet.

I am using [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) link for getting datetime format codes but I can't find any code that really helps me achieve my goal.

Comment: Formatting dates is a job for the presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: Also please, please, please [don't specify `varchar` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no exact match for the required format you need - you can either use

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), SYSDATETIME(), 104), '.', '')
```

(*use what you had and just strip out the `.` after first step of formatting*)

or you can use `FORMAT` which is available in SQL Server 2012 and newer:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'ddMMyyyy')
```

Comment: Why use `SYSDATETIME` ? I know it provides more accuracy, but that all gets stripped off by the formatting...

Comment: @PeterB: *because* it offers support for all date&time datatypes, I've just gotten into the habit to use `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` (which **always** "only" returns a `DATETIME` - warts and all)

Comment: @PeterB it's okay, it was just an example though I am not using `GetDate()` or `SYSDATETIME()`  currently. But It helped too. Thank you to you too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined format that fulfills your request. However, you can use the 'Replace' function to strip your value from date separators.

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),104),'.','')
```

OR use the newer FORMAT function (SQL server 2012+)

```
 SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'ddMMyyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function to complete it.

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 104),'.','')
```